# Illegal entry in Gradle Dependencies for org.apache.commons commons-imaging 1.0-alpha2-SNAPSHOT

Tags: eclipse, gradle, apache-commons-imaging

I just add `compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-imaging:1.0-alpha2-SNAPSHOT'` to file build.gradle, when I run Gradle Refresh Dependencies, I got an error as below, what can I do?

```
Illegal entry in Gradle Dependencies: C:/eclipse/unresolved dependency - org.apache.commons commons-imaging 1.0-alpha2-SNAPSHOT
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you want to use version `1.0-alpha2-SNAPSHOT` of this lib which does not seem to be available on public maven repos (even not in apache snapshots repo.)

Try to use a released version instead (`1.0-alpha1`)

```
dependencies{
     compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-imaging', version: '1.0-alpha1'

}
```

Comment: This one is ok `compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-imaging:1.0-alpha1'`

Comment: good. better to use non-snapshot version . i'll update my answer